# 406 Not Acceptable with this simple form

Tags: html

I have this simple form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post"  >
<textarea name="howtouse" rows="10" cols="30">
    <p></p>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

When I submit form it show

```
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /testing/test.php
could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The live code is at http://goo.gl/SaFf5D

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://w2cschool.com/How/How-To-Manage-Not-Acceptable-406-error-On-Godday-Server-/1170 solved the problem.

As mentioned by Brad this is not really related to client side code.

The problem is godaddy blocking some format of the **name**.

In short, the problem can be solved by changing

```
<textarea name="howtouse" rows="10" cols="30">
```

to

```
<textarea name="body1" rows="10" cols="30">
```